# How to reduce two Flux to generate a reduced HashMap, Reactive Java Spring WebFlux Reactor

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have two data structures:

```
Flux<Set<Integer>> combinationsFlux = Flux.fromIterable(
Set.of(
    Set.of(1, 2),
    Set.of(1, 3),
    Set.of(2, 3)));

Flux<Answer> answersFlux = Flux.fromIterable(List.of(
    new Answer(1, Set.of(2)),
    new Answer(5, Set.of(1)),
    new Answer(1, Set.of(2, 3)),
    new Answer(2, Set.of(3, 1)))
```

Answer is a simple Class that represents the response of the Database(ReactiveRepository):

```
public class Answer {

  private int count;

  private Set<Integer> values;
}
```

I need to group in a HashMap putting the combinations as key and the sum of the counts of answers that match with any of the values of each combination, the result I need would be something like:

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1,2 | 7 |
| 1,3 | 8 |
| 2,3 | 4 |

I have tried to do it this way:

```
combinationsFlux
    .collectMap(
        combination -> combination,
        combination ->
            answersFlux
                .log()
                .reduce(0, (respondentsCount, answer) -> {
                      if (answer
                          .getValues()
                          .stream()
                          .anyMatch(combination::contains)) {
                        respondentsCount = respondentsCount + answer.getCount();
                      }
                      return respondentsCount;
                    }
                )
    );
```

but at the end I'm not getting the correct structure, it seems to be a problem on the reduce part and I get something like this when logging the Flux:

```
2022-12-01 16:54:34.691  INFO 203887 --- [or-http-epoll-2] reactor.Flux.MonoFlatMapMany.3           : onNext([1, 2]=MonoReduceSeed)
2022-12-01 16:54:34.691  INFO 203887 --- [or-http-epoll-2] reactor.Flux.MonoFlatMapMany.3           : onNext([1, 3]=MonoReduceSeed)
2022-12-01 16:54:34.691  INFO 203887 --- [or-http-epoll-2] reactor.Flux.MonoFlatMapMany.3           : onNext([2, 3]=MonoReduceSeed)
```

I get that MonoReduceSeed object instead of the expected integer. Any suggestion?

Comment: what's the final output of your program?

Comment: The result right now is a: Mono<Map<Set<Integer>, Mono<Integer>>> result with the following entries: [1, 2]=MonoReduceSeed, [1, 3]=MonoReduceSeed, [2, 3]=MonoReduceSeed and I want it to be a Mono<Map<Set<Integer>, Integer>>  with the entries: [1, 2]=7, [1, 3]=8, [2, 3]=4

Comment: collectMap doesn't work like `flatMap`, the functions you pass to it shouldn't return a Mono/Flux. Or at least it aggregates what you return, without unwrapping it.   
In your case the `reduce` over `answersFlux` is returning a `Mono<Integer>`, but it doesn't resolves it, you can explicitly `.block()` on it to resolve it

Comment: The thing is that is not possible to use block there, when I use it I get the error: "block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-epoll-2"